# AtiveMQ Custom Authentication using BrokerFilter

Tags: activemq-classic, custom-authentication

I am creating my own authentication plugin for my ActiveMQ broker, using BrokerFilter. I followed steps from this guide:

http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2014/01/04/ip-based-authentication-plugin-for-activemq/

Everything works fine in standalone mode. However when I try to deploy a cluster of brokers, the network connections between brokers have been intercepted by my addConnection() method, and since it's not pass my authentication logic, the clusters cannot be connected.

In short, my question is: how can I distinguish between connections from clients and connections from other broker in my context? I have looked at both ConnectionContext and ConnectionInfo objects but seems like none of them work.

Many thanks.

Comment: A question comes to mind. Why leave such a back door open? I.e. Fire up a local broker and setup a network connection and you have full access to the network while a simple client would require authentication check.

Comment: ConnectionContext.isNetworkConnection should tell you

Comment: I've already tried ConnectionContext.isNetworkConnection but it returns false in my case.